# Image doesn't show

Tags: php, image, src

I have written the correct image source/folder but the image is not displayed. Did I miss something?

`echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/menu/'.$obj->MenuPicture.'"></div>';`

Comment: Are you missing the file extension? Try using `echo $obj->MenuPicture;` to see if you've got the right path.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$obj` to see if it's really correct.

Comment: Can you hit 'view source' in your web browser, and post the HTML that is served to the browser?

Comment: You need to verify the given path is correct

Comment: Okay. After checking "view frame source", I noticed the repeated folder

<img src="images/menu/images/menu/nasi katok.jpg">

Why is that and how to make the image shown? @mti2935

Comment: @SaminBhp, replace `src` with this `src="'.$obj->MenuPicture.'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<img src="images/menu/'.$obj->MenuPicture.'">
```

to

```
<img src="'.$obj->MenuPicture.'" />
```

I addedd the "/" at the end of the tag for W3C compliance.